# Go protobuf packages collision

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Hi I am trying to generate the simple protobuf file in Go language

```
syntax = "proto3";

package gen;

message EvtKeepAlive
{

   string SvcName   = 2;

}
```

In the header I see that the package uses two different proto go implementations, one from **github.com** and one from **google.golang.org**. As far as I understand the latter supersedes the former, so is this file generation valid?

```
// versions:
//  protoc-gen-go v1.25.0-devel
//  protoc        v3.13.0
// source: common.proto

package gen

import (
    proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    protoreflect "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
    protoimpl "google.golang.org/protobuf/runtime/protoimpl"
    reflect "reflect"
    sync "sync"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is valid; see the comments from dsnet in response to [this issue](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1077):

> The only reason the newly generated .pb.go files depend on the
> deprecated proto package is to enforce a weak dependency on a
> sufficiently new version of the legacy package. This is necessary
> because not everyone is using Go modules such that the Go toolchain
> would enforce this dependency constraint. I wasn't fond of adding it,
> but I think it's probably necessary to keep at least for a few months.